# applyCss doesn't work when remove a styleClass

Tags: css, javafx, textfield, javafx-8

I have a `TextField` styled by changing `styleClass` when its value is valid/invalid but there is a great problem. When the value becomes valid I still should change the `TextField` once more to make the `styleClass` be applied. I tried with `applyCss()` method just after, but it didn't work :(.

```
    if(!valid){
        field.getStyleClass().add("invalid-field");//Works excellent
    } else {
        field.getStyleClass().remove("invalid-field");//Doesn't work up to the time textProperty doesn't change once again
        field.applyCss();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common cause of these bugs is that you may have added the "invalid-field" style class more than once. (Remember, `getStyleClass()` returns a `List<String>`, not a `Set<String>`.) So you should probably take steps to make sure the style class is only added once, or take steps to remove all occurrences when you remove it.

I like to do both (where I come from, we call this a "belt and braces approach").

```
ObservableList<String> styleClasses = field.getStyleClass();
if(!valid)
    if( ! styleClass.contains("invalid-field")){
        styleClass.add("invalid-field");
    } 
} else {
    // remove all occurrences:
    styleClass.removeAll(Collections.singleton("invalid-field"));
}
```